# Calling a Function After New Post Creation for a WordPress Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks

Assume I created a new post type `'product'`. Is there a way to perform a function (user created) when this new `'product'` post has been created?

Comment: *@dotty*: Do any of these answers below help you solve your problem? If so, please up vote them to thank the people who've helped you, and pick the best answer so your question doesn't remain in the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 5):

In functions.php:

```
function mynewproduct(){
    myfunction();
}
add_action( 'new_product', 'mynewproduct' );
```

For more and the official documentation, refer here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

Comment: I don't think `new_{post_type}` will work because the `status` in the `{status}_{post_type}` action will never be set to `new`.

Comment: In this case it pays to know what's meant by 'created'

Answer (score 3):

Hi **@dotty:**

Take a look at the end of the `wp_insert_post()` function in the file `/wp-includes/post.php` (on lines 2148 thru 2392 in WordPress 3.0.1. *Note that WordPress uses this function both for adding and updating posts.*)

At the end it has the following code. From this code you can identify the call to `wp_transition_post_status()` (more on that in a bit) and we have the action hooks `edit_post`, `post_updated`, `save_post` and `wp_insert_post` (*frankly I don't know why we have the latter two instead of just one.*) You can use any of those that are appropriate for your needs:

```
<?php
wp_transition_post_status($data['post_status'], $previous_status, $post);
if ( $update ) {
  do_action('edit_post', $post_ID, $post);
  $post_after = get_post($post_ID);
  do_action( 'post_updated', $post_ID, $post_after, $post_before);
}
do_action('save_post', $post_ID, $post);
do_action('wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post);
return $post_ID;
```

And as *@Jan Fabry* mentioned there are the action hooks found in `wp_transition_post_status()` (on 2713 thru 2717 of `/wp-includes/post.php` in WordPress 3.0.1.) Note there are three of them; use as appropriate:

```
<?php
function wp_transition_post_status($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
  do_action('transition_post_status', $new_status, $old_status, $post);
  do_action("${old_status}_to_$new_status", $post);
  do_action("${new_status}_$post->post_type", $post->ID, $post);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`wp_transition_post_status`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/post.php#L2714) function will be called, and this will trigger the action `"${new_status}_$post->post_type"`, so if a `product` moves to the `publish` state, the action `publish_product` will be triggered.

Comment: So i assign my function to the publish_product action?

Comment: @dotty: You can do that, but if a user creates a product but does not yet click "Publish", this hook will not be triggered. This may or may not be what you want.