# Any Hook Called When Post Becomes Published?

Tags: customization, hooks

Posts may be published either immediately or in the future.

Suppose a plug-in wants to do something at the moment when the post becomes published and visible on the blog (I don't mean when the post is saved as published in the admin panel with  whatever date). Is there a hook like "post_visible" or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a post changes status, [`wp_transition_post_status`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/post.php#L2714) function will be called. This triggers the actions `${old_status}_to_${new_status}` and `${new_status}_${post->post_type}`, so for example `publish_post` will be triggered here. A post with a date in the future will have the status `future` until it is actually published, so this should work for you.

Comment: Could you please give an example of the action names . Will the actions triggered be "future_to_published" and "publish_post"?

Comment: Indeed, `publish_post` will certainly be triggered, and `future_to_publish` if the previous status was `future` (I don't know the initial status if you publish immediately). Mike also gave some interesting hooks in [an answer to a related question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1414/calling-a-function-after-new-post-creation-for-a-wordpress-custom-post-type/1442#1442).